# int *p=&a++ and int *p=&++a

Tags: c, operator-keyword

The code is simple,I just want to test the priority between & and ++.

```
int main()
{
    int a=10;
    int *p;
    int *q;
    p=&++a;//error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
    q=&a++;//error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
    return 0;
}
```

when **gcc** compile it, two errors came out. In my opinion，`a++` is a right value，but the `++a` is a lvalue，so it should not be an error when use & to get it address，

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you have misunderstood the difference between `lvalue` and `rvalue`. In your case both the expressions `a++` and `++a` are `rvalues` and cannot be assigned.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3601661/391161) is a good description of the distinction, but the quick way to tell whether it is an `lvalue` is to see whether you get an error if you put it on the left side of an `=`.

Observe that both of the following two statements produce the same error you describe.

```
++a = 5;
a++ = 6;
```

Update: As @mafso mentioned below, `++a` is indeed an `lvalue` in the language `c++`, and you will not see the error for that expression when compiling with `g++`.

Comment: @storen Please accept the answer if it resolved your question.

Answer (score -1):

the object of operator &  is `lvalue` , an the same is operator ++.but after ++a is done , it returns `rvalue` , that's the reason wrong.